# Selenium browser automation session expires when wait for 7 mins

Tags: python, selenium

I run selenium in python to do web testing, and I have noticed that, when I have added a longer wait in python, my selenium session is logged-out after a certain point of time.

*Below Line of code I use to wait in the code*

```
time.sleep(420)
```

I have tried to do some fake click during the wait period, but still, I have seen the security logout. is there any approach I can solve this issue?

I use **python 3.5** and **firefox web driver** for testing.

Comment: Just because of curiosity, why do you use so long sleeps in your tests?

Comment: i have pushed few configuration to client system , that will take more than 6 minute to apply in client system. so i have to wait till that process is completed in my code.

Comment: Is it possible to push the configurations before you start WebDriver?

Comment: Can you share code for that *fake click* also?

Comment: using web driver i m pushing these configuration. i didnt want to quit webdriver and open back again only for this purpose.

Comment: fake click by i meant to click on any xpath which is not necessary for test.

Comment: Yeah, I understand that. Where is the code for the same?

Answer (score 0):

What if you try to insert also a wait to Selenium.

In Java it looks like: `SeleniumUtils.sleepQuietly(420);`

There should also be a method for Python how to tell Selenium to wait (sleep) for certain time.

In your case, you have to say Selenium to wait, after you have called "the function" or click the button that needs to long (6 minutes) to execute.

Answer (score 0):

when you use sleep() function you cannot do anything in that time. that is very useful between two lines of code where you need some time for processing like you are downloading file so, wait 5 seconds after 5 seconds add new parameters and download another file something like that.
you can surely do clicks without having sleep() function. between to click use sleep of 5 to 10 seconds like this your session will not expire it will run until you do driver.quit().